# authorization crud ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm starting with ruby on rails , and I want to know how to prevent a user to edit a record that is not the , this is my code:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index , :show]
    def index
        @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @pin = current_user.pins.build
    end

    def create
        @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

        if @pin.save
            redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin creado"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @pin.update(pin_params)
            redirect_to @pin, notice: "Actualizado correctamente"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @pin.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def upvote
        @pin.upvote_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
    end

    private

    def pin_params
        params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image)
    end

    def find_pin
        @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

and also in the view I have two buttons, one to edit and delete another , as I can do so only if you aparescan is the creator of the record ?

Comment: Please proofread your question. You seem to be missing what appears to be a very important word: "prevent a user to edit a record that is not the ,"

Comment: Do it the same way you do it in your 'new' and 'create' actions, use 'current_user.pins', that would give you only the pins that belong to the logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
before_action :set_user_pins, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :show]

def set_user_pins
  @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_request if @pin.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update action, instead of this: `if @pin.update(pin_params)`

do something like this:

```
pin = current_user&.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
if pin
  # do the update here because the pin belongs to current_user
else
  # raise a 403 'permission denied' error or something
end
```

in case you're not familiar with the safe navigation operator, `user&.pins` is the same as `if !user.nil? then user.pins else nil end`.

So for ruby versios before 2.3 you can do `pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id]) if current_user`